# How do I login with multiple discord bot accounts WITHOUT hardcoding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, foreach, discord.js

I have been trying to get this to work for a bit now, with no avail.

What i have tried is below, what i want to be able to do is have multiple discord bot accounts respond to the same prompts at the same time, without hardcoding it, my best example so far is down below.

EDIT: I know about the client.on error, but this is the best example that has gotten this far I have had

```
const auth = require("./tokens.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
client = new Discord.Client();
var clients = [];
auth["Tokens"].forEach(element => {
    console.log(clients)
    clients.push(new Discord.Client().login(element));
    console.log(clients)
});
console.log(clients[0])
console.log(clients[1])
console.log(clients[2])

clients.forEach(client => {
    client.on("ready", () => {
        console.log("I am ready!");
        console.log(client.user.id)
    });
});
```

My tokens.json code:

```
{
    "Tokens": ["MjIxtokentoken","MjIxtokentokenc","MjIxtokentoken"]
}
```

The output:

```
PS E:\test> node app.js
[]
[ Promise { <pending> } ]
[ Promise { <pending> } ]
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
E:\test\app.js:40
    client.on("ready", () => {
           ^

TypeError: client.on is not a function
    at E:\test\app.js:40:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\test\app.js:39:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Comment: `clients.push(new Discord.Client().login(element))` appends a login promise instead of a client.  Instead `const c = new Discord.Client(); c.login(element); clients.push(c);` but also handle promise in some other way as well.

Comment: @Aivaras Wouldn't that const be overwritten everytime the foreach is iterated, therefore having the value of only the last auth token?

Comment: No it is created for each iteration inside that function and not accessible from the outside. I mean `auth["Tokens"].forEach(t => {const c = new Discord.Client(); c.login(t); clients.push(c);});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in a simple way. At first do a loop on a your tokens and do your job.

This will look likes:

```js
const auth = require('./tokens.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

for (const token of auth.Tokens) {
    const client = new Discord.Client()
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('I am ready !')
        console.log(client.user.id)
    })
    client.login(token)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Git to your developing workflow. You can push your code (which only logins with one token) to a GitHub repo. Note, you need to put the *node_modules* folder in the .gitignore, before committing to the repo. After the push is done, use git clone, and rename the main clone folder in Git Bash:

```
mv {yourClonedRepoFolder} {nameForTheSameFolderButNewName}
```

Then you can replace the token with the respective token for each clone. And done!!

This is advantageous, as you can change the code for each bot.

Comment: Both mine and @Tanuki 's code help. But, my approach is different.